# calling agent from XPages - login form appears

Tags: java, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I am calling an agent from an XPage via SSJS:

```
importPackage(java.net);
importPackage(java.io);

var protocol = context.getUrl().getScheme();    
var host = context.getUrl().getHost();
var url = protocol + "://" + host;
var path = env["dir_path"];
var dbName = datasource["db_app_filepath"];
var agentRef = "response?OpenAgent";
var paramName = "custId";

var urlAgent = url + "/" + path + dbName + "/" + agentRef;
var agent:URL = new URL(urlAgent);
var agentConnection:URLConnection = agent.openConnection();
var inputReader:BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(agentConnection.getInputStream()));
var res:String="";
while ((inputLine = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
    res+=inputLine;
}
print("value form agent = " + res);
```

The agent just returns a simple string:

```
Option Public
Option Declare

Sub Initialize
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim creator As String
    creator = session.EffectiveUserName
    Print "Hello World " + creator
End Sub
```

But in the print statement in the console I see that the login form is presented.

If I access the agent directly in a browser window I get as example returned:

> Hello World CN=§Unrestricted §Signer/OU=System/O=ACME

This is the username which I have set in the Run on behalf of property in the agent.

On the XPage I am already authenticated.

Should I provide the credentials in my call or?

The idea behind the code is that I want to check if the user is not creating double entries for a type of object. The objects (Notes documents) have Readers restriction so user X may not see user Y's entries.

Comment: The backend SSJS code is calling the agent as anonymous and is therefore authenticated. So either allow the agent to be run as anonymous or provide credentials

Comment: do you really want to call it via HTTP?

Comment: @FrantisekKossuth my code has not left my dev environment...

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten how can I include the credentials?

Comment: @PatrickKwinten I believe that you need to use basic authentication. But instead you should take a look at building the desired functionality as SSJS or Java that your existing SSJS code can call.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten I need to check if other users have not registered documents with the same reference. all documents have Readers field and the current user can not read them. sessionassigner might work well in my case I guess http://www.tlcc.com/admin/tips.nsf/0/1DE6DF4625222A53852577900056EADB

Comment: @PatrickKwinten yes, sessionAsSigner can work assuming the signer has the necessasry read access. Otherwise you can use sessionAsSignerWithFullAccess

Answer (score 3):

ODA has a method for this purpose and if you use the native server session, it should have access - if the server doesn't have access, you'll have a bigger problem at some point with your application.

`Factory.getSession(SessionType.NATIVE).getDatabase(filePath).getView("myView").checkUnique(key, Document)`

`checkUnique()` takes an object of the key(s) in the view to check against uniqueness, and the current document. Obviously if a user re-saves a document, it will be unique in the view, so you don't want to throw an error. Similarly, if the keys can be changed, just performing the check on creation will not prevent uniques.

Comment: nice feature. been asking for ODA for a while but still not approved. how about running code on behalf of another signer?

Comment: `SessionAsSigner` would be an alternative approach.

Comment: sessionassigner seems to be a good approach in my case. never used it before.

Comment: Ensure only one signer for the application or there will be problems

Answer (score 0):

You do need to provide credentials if you want to call an agent via http(s). You could do this using the https://username:password@restofurl format. Of course that’s a headache to maintain.

**Update**
Verify what gets stored in the log. A Browser would convert that syntax into a Basic Auth header and a normal URL. In Java you might need to create that header yourself. 
**/Update**

The alternative that might work for you: since your browser is authenticated, use an Ajax call from the browser to trigger the agent.

Try that if `sessionAsSigner` isn’t the user you want to run with.

Of course: don’t do agents is best. You could have a managed bean that creates its own server.id based session.

Comment: that username/pwd in url will be logged everywhere along the net path, including domlog.nsf. don't do this

Comment: @stwissel can you explain the latter one, managed bean with server id based session?

Comment: NotesFactory.createSession() https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_NOTESFACTORY_CLASS_JAVA.html